# How do I get the globe off this ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan

[image]
I have tried pulling down on the globe thinking the metal clasps were holding the globe with tension. I've tried turning the globe but the whole base turns when I do that. 
I'm not sure what brand it is so I am including a picture. 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: @CandaceWooten Please accept Daniel's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Hold the glass bowl steady, and turn that metal piece at the bottom counter-clockwise. It's a fancy-looking nut, threaded onto a rod, holding the bowl up. (The clips are a bit strange, but are likely some sort of reinforcement for the bowl, and not the point of release.)

Comment: We have globes w/ the camps.  They serve primarily to hold the globe steady (from tipping over) but do tend to require one clamp to be pulled away from the globe for it to be slid out of the other two clamps.  I wouldn't trust the clamps to support the globe while the decorative "nut" is unscrewed.